# String builder vs string concatenation

Tags: java, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

What is the benefit and trade-off of using a string builder over pure string concatenation?

```
new StringBuilder(32).append(str1)
                     .append(" test: ")
                     .append(val)
                     .append(" is changed")
                     .toString();
```

vs say

```
str1 + " test: " + val + " is changed".
```

`str1` is a random 10 character string.
`str2` is a random 8 character string.

Comment: In your trivial example, there may be no benefit.  StringBuilders are useful because, when you concat with + you create brand new strings every time you concat.  StringBuilder is therefore more efficient for concat'ing large numbers of strings.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In your particular example, none because the compiler internally uses `StringBuilder`s to do String concatenation.  If the concatenation occurred in a loop, however, the compiler could create several `StringBuilder` and `String` objects.  For example:

```
String s= "" ;
for(int i= 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    s+= "a" ;
```

Each time line 3 above is executed, a new `StringBuilder` object is created, the contents of `s` appended, "a" appended, and then the `StringBuilder` is converted into a String to be assigned back to `s`.  A total of 10 `StringBuilder`s and 10 `String`s.

Conversely, in

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder() ;
for(int i= 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
    sb.append( "a" );
String s= sb.toString() ;
```

Only 1 `StringBuilder` and 1 `String` are created.

The main reason for this is that the compiler could not be smart enough to understand that the first loop is equivalent to the second and generate more efficient (byte) code.  In more complex cases, it's impossible even for the smartest compiler to know.  If you absolutely need this optimization, you have to introduce it manually by using `StringBuilder`s explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

The quick answer is the performance:
when you are using native String classes it operates immutable strings, which means when you are writing

```
  String line = "java";
  String sufix = " is awesome";
  line = line + sufix;
```

it will create two strings "java" and " is awesome", than create a new third string "java is awesome" from previous two ("java" and "is awesome") which later are likely to be deleted by a garbage collector (because they are no more used in app). That is a slow solution.

More faster solution is an appliance of StringBuffer class which through the smart algorightms that provide a buffer (that is obvious from its name) for merging strings and as a result would not remove the initial string during the concatenation process.

In case you are writing single thread-application (no concurrancy issues during which multiple threads access same object) it is better to apply StringBuilder which has even faster performance than the initial StringBuffer class.

Comment: Hi, like Thread safe data structures, you suggest using a Thread safe version of String Builder in multi threaded execution ?