# Method to create the sql query?

Tags: java, sql

Is it possible to create java method which created this SQL query programatically  depends on the arrayList size since the arrayList size is 22 sometimes?

I appreciate any help!

```
private String create_sql_order_query(ArrayList<String> nameNumber) {

String sql_find_order2 = "SELECT s2.stop_id  FROM stops s1"
        + " JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1"
        + " WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name) = CONCAT(?,?)";

String sql_find_order3 = "SELECT s3.stop_id  FROM stops s1"
        + " JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1"
        + " JOIN stops s3 ON s2.stop_id = s3.stop_id - 1"
        + " WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name) = CONCAT(?,?,?)";

String sql_find_order4 = "SELECT s4.stop_id  FROM stops s1"
        + " JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1"
        + " JOIN stops s3 ON s2.stop_id = s3.stop_id - 1"
        + " JOIN stops s4 ON s3.stop_id = s4.stop_id - 1 "
        + " WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name, s4.name) = CONCAT(?,?,?,?)";

String sql_find_order5 = "SELECT s5.stop_id  FROM stops s1"
        + " JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1"
        + " JOIN stops s3 ON s2.stop_id = s3.stop_id - 1"
        + " JOIN stops s4 ON s3.stop_id = s4.stop_id - 1 "
        + " JOIN stops s5 ON s4.stop_id = s5.stop_id - 1"
        + " WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name, s4.name) = CONCAT(?,?,?,?,?)";
  .
  .
  .
  .
return "";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to improve, but i think you get the idea:

```
private String createSqlStatement(int size) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("SELECT s").append(size + 1).append(".stop_id  FROM stops s1 ").append("\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        sb.append("  JOIN stops s").append(i + 1).append(" ON s").append(i).append(".stop_id = s").append(i + 1).append(".stop_id - 1")
                .append("\n");
    }
    sb.append(" WHERE CONCAT(");
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        sb.append("s").append(i).append(".name,");
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    sb.append(") = CONCAT(");
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        sb.append("?,");
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    sb.append(");");

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way, but easy to figure out...

```
ArrayList<String> nameNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
        nameNumber.add("foo");
        nameNumber.add("bar");
        nameNumber.add("baz");

        String sql_find_order = "SELECT s" + nameNumber.size() + ".stop_id  FROM stops s1";
        String putInWhere1 = "";
        String putInWhere2 = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < nameNumber.size(); i++) {
            sql_find_order += " JOIN stops s" + (i + 2) + " ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1";
            putInWhere1 += ", s" + (i + 1) + ".name";
            putInWhere2 += ", ?";
        }

        sql_find_order += " WHERE CONCAT(" + putInWhere1.substring(2) + ") = CONCAT(" + putInWhere2.substring(2) + ")";
        System.out.println(sql_find_order);
```

Result

```
SELECT s3.stop_id  FROM stops s1 JOIN stops s2 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1 JOIN stops s3 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1 JOIN stops s4 ON s1.stop_id = s2.stop_id - 1 WHERE CONCAT(s1.name, s2.name, s3.name) = CONCAT(?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: I would use a StringBuilder instead of String concatenation (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453458/string-builder-vs-string-concatenation)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Like I said it's not the most efficient way, but an easy approach.