# Java auto print without popup dialog box

Tags: java, thermal-printer

How can I automatically print without poping up dialog box or automatically accept print dialog? Here is some of my code:

```
if ("OUT".equals(rs.getString("empattendance"))) {
    String date  = dft.format(dNow);
    String time = tft.format(dNow);
    textArea.setText(date + "\n" + "\n" + 
              fullname +"\n" +
              "Time In: " + time + "\n" +
              "Status: "+ statusin +
              "\n" +
              "\n" +
              "____________________\n" +
              " Sign by Supervisor");
    try {
        //printing
        Boolean complete = textArea.print();
        if(complete){
        }
        else{
        }
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and here's [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYETz.png) of the current behaviour.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your code I have few thoughts before answer. 
1) Do not use `String`. Better for comparing stuff is Enumerators I believe.
2) If you would like to set text to `textArea` previously create some method using `StringBuilder` for example which will be creating the `String` you would like to set. Joshua Bloch says

> **Item 15: minimize mutability** (...) If a client requires performing expensive multi-stage operations on your class, expose them as primitive methods, or provide a mutable companion class (like StringBuilder for String).

And take a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453458/string-builder-vs-string-concatenation) for more.
3) To print data from `textArea` if I were you I would try to use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html).

I believe that would help you

Comment: he is asking the print popup dialog. And you give another non-related answer?