# Why does my String turn into Integers instead of letters after I add characters with +?

Tags: java, string

So this is the task: Given a string, return a string where for every char in the original, there are two chars.

And I don't understand why its output are numbers instead of letters, I tried doesn't work?

```
public String doubleChar(String str) {
  String s = "";
  for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
  s +=  str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
  
  }
    return s;
}
```

Expected :

> doubleChar("The") → "TThhee"
>
> doubleChar("AAbb") → "AAAAbbbb"

Output:

> doubleChar("The") → "168208202"
>
> doubleChar("AAbb") → "130130196196"

Comment: Adding two `char`s doesn't give you a string with those two characters, but rather [an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char) with numerical value equal to the sum of the two characters' numerical values.

Comment: Man, I thought this would be a perfect example to introduce a novice Java user to Java streams, and boy, it's a disaster! https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/Java-Double-chars-using-Streams Compare: https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/Double-chars-using-Streams-Swift

Comment: @Alexander There is much simpler, even in java:`    public static String doubleCharacters(String input) {
        return input.chars()
                .mapToObj(c -> "" + (char)c + (char)c)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
`

Comment: @Alexander @Benoit : Even more efficient (only one temporary array, no boxing/unboxing), with fewer ugly casts and doesn't mangle asian text that use surrogate char pairs: `new String(str.codePoints().flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(i, i)).toArray(), 0, str.length() * 2);`

Comment: @Benoit I was trying to avoid the heap allocation for all those small strings. Though I think Java uses tagged pointers to optimize away the heap allocations for that, so maybe it's okay

Comment: @LordOfThePigs Great stuff. I wonder, does String defensively copy an array like this, or does it just take ownership and use it as its backing storage?

Comment: @Alexander String always does a defensive copy, it's the only way it can guarantee immutability in all cases. Doing it in a good old for-loop with manual array manipulations is still the fastest (no extra method calls, no IntStream allocations, etc...), but streams give you a cute one-liner.

Comment: @stevie lol when you add characters in Java it adds ascii value for same.Here you are adding this ascii value to String so you are getting ascii value appended one after another.

Answer (score 54):

In Java the `char` primitive type is basically just a numeric value that maps to a character, so if you add two `char` values together they produce a number and not another `char` (and not a `String`) so you end up with an `int` as you're seeing.

To fix this you can use the [`Character.toString(char)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(char)) like this:

```
s += Character.toString(str.charAt(i)) + Character.toString(str.charAt(i))
```

But this is all fairly inefficient because you're doing this in a loop and so string concatenation is producing a lot of `String` objects needlessly. More efficient is to use a `StringBuilder` and its `append(char)` method like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length() * 2);
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    sb.append(c).append(c);
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: This should be correct answer. Creating new String objects each loop iteration is not good practice. Using a StringBuilder is more efficient. Look here for exaplanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453485/8685250

Comment: At least since Java 8 the compiler is converting regular string concats to stringbuilder constructs where it helps. There is no need to make your code less clear or more complicated of the compiler can optimize better, anyways

Comment: @marstato that is true, but it doesn't apply in this case. The Java compiler will indeed convert sequences of string concatenations to sequences of StringBuilder.append. That will cover the `s += s1 + s2` statement inside the `for` block, but it will be compiled such that each execution of this statement creates its own `StringBuilder`. Manually creaing it outside of the loop won't have this issue.

Comment: @marstato LordOfThePigs is right: the problem with string concatenation within a loop is that it forces the creation of a new `StringBuilder` object for every iteration. Also, the default capacity of a `StringBuilder` is only 16 characters, so a lot of appending will force numerous resizes, thus creating more objects. I have created a JMH benchmark to test this and found that in a loop of 1000 iterations, String concatenation generates 11MiB of garbage, and runs at 876 ops/sec, while a `StringBuilder` with optimum capacity generates only 29KiB of garbage and runs at 39,734 ops/sec.

Comment: @Edward they are just passing down useful information. You have to remember how much "magic" happens behind the scenes in Java. It isn't like other languages, where the most efficient way is the most obvious way.

Answer (score 23):

### Why does it output integers?

The + operator is overloaded in Java to perform String concatenation only for `String`s, not `char`s.

From the [Java Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18):

> If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the
>   operation is string concatenation.
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must be
>   a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.

In your case, char is converted to its primitive value (int), then added.

Instead, use [`StringBuilder.append(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(char)) to concatenate them into a `String`.

If performance is not a concern, you could even do:

```
char c = 'A';
String s = "" + c + c;
```

and `s += "" + c + c;`

That will force the + `String` concatenation operator because it starts with a `String` (""). The Java Spec above explains with examples:

> The + operator is syntactically left-associative, no matter whether it
>   is determined by type analysis to represent string concatenation or
>   numeric addition. In some cases care is required to get the desired
>   result. For example [...]
>
> `1 + 2 + " fiddlers"` is `"3 fiddlers"`
>
> but the result of:
>
> `"fiddlers " + 1 + 2` is `"fiddlers 12"`

Answer (score 12):

You are adding numeric values of chars first before concatenating the result (now integer) to the string. Try debugging with print statements:

```
public static String doubleChar(String str) {
  String s = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i));
    s += str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
  }
  return s;
}
```

The more efficient way of doing what you want is:

```
public static String doubleChar(String str) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length() * 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    sb.append(c).append(c);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I agree he should be using `StringBuilder` since he is concatenating a `String` inside of a loop, but it may be helpful to explain briefly why it is better.

Comment: At least since Java 8 the compiler is converting regular string concats to stringbuilder constructs where it helps. There is no need to make your code less clear or more complicated of the compiler can optimize better, anyways

Comment: @marstato Using the stringbuilder is *at least* as clear as any solution not using the string builder.  It also offers the opportunity to initialize the string builder to the right size (and I doubt the compiler reliably does that).

Comment: @marstato compiler would only convert concatenation of strings into a string builder inside of the loop. A new string and string builder would be created on every iteration AFAIK.

Comment: A better suggestion is to try debugging with a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the *value* of two characters together.  Change the `String` concatenation from:

```
s +=  str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

To:

```
s +=  str.charAt(i) + "" + str.charAt(i);
```

Which will ensure the characters convert to a `String`.

Note:  This is a quick fix, and you should use `StringBuilder` when `String` concatenating inside of a loop.  See the other answers for how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

`String.charAt()` returns a `char` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) so you're dealing with a single character. With one`char`, you can perform operations on it like this (which will print "65" which is ASCII value for the 'A' character):

```
System.out.println('A' + 0);
```

you can print the ASCII value for the next character ("B") by adding 1 to `'A'`, like this:

```
System.out.println('A' + 1);
```

To make your code work – so that it doubles each character – there are number of options. You could append each character one at a time:

```
s += str.charAt(i);
s += str.charAt(i);
```

or various ways of casting the operation to a string:

```
s += "" + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

Comment: `s = s + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);` probably also works, I guess?